# What is the purpose of the VOLUME instruction in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

In the documentation it says that the VOLUME instruction creates a mount point but I created a image using:

```
FROM alpine
RUN mkdir /myvol
RUN echo "hello world" > /myvol/greeting
```

and I was able to `mount /myvol` or any any other path on the containers file system using `docker run -v vol:/myvol myimage` and was able to see the data there in `/var/lib/docker/vol/_data` on the host machine.

What difference would adding `VOLUME myvol` to the Docker file make?

Comment: Would you like to add a link to the documentation and a small quotation of the relevant section in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the Dockerfile (`VOLUME /myvol`) the Mountpoint (`/myvol`) will be created (inspect with `docker run -it --rm ${YOURCONTAINER_IMAGE} /bin/bash`):

```
mount | grep myvol
/dev/mapper/host--vg-var on /myvol type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

The Mountpoint will be a temporary Docker-Volume on your Host:

```
de5a4052ac6f48788baf17ed66efa603eb89aa023aac7768688839ec6df7dbec/_data/the_data_within_myvol
```

After running (`docker run -v vol:/myvol myimage`) also the Volume `vol` will be created and earns all the files within your container under (`/myvol`).

The difference is the way you create it (within the Dockerfile, or with `docker run -v`).

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/a/959475/128101 - the gist of which is that VOLUME is interesting when sharing volumes between containers with `--volumes-from <container>`